# Copy text of cell after hyperlink click

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I do have a list of names in sheet "Database" and through a macro I create an hyperlink for each cell of the list, pointing to the same cell A1 of Sheet "Foglio2".
here follows the code:

```
    Sub InserisciHyperlink()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Database")
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range

LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Range("A2"), ws.Range("A" & LastRow))
For Each cell In rng
    ws.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=cell, Address:="", SubAddress:="Foglio2!A1", TextToDisplay:=cell.Value
Next

End Sub
```

The problem arises when I try to have the text of clicked hyperlink copied into cell A1 of Sheet "Foglio2".

I put following code inside Sheet "Foglio2":

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Database")
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range

LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Range("A2"), ws.Range("A" & LastRow))

If Not Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then
    Sheets("Foglio2").Range("A1").Value = TargetCell.Value
    Sheets("Foglio2").Select
End If

End Sub
```

but after clicking on any of the hyperlinks I created, I receive the error message `Runtime error 13`, with the debugger underlining the following string

```
If Not Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then
```

Comment: `Target` is a `Hyperlink` object and `rng` is a  `Range`. You can only intersect ranges. Check `Target.Range` instead.

Comment: The code should go into worksheet `Database`, that's where you're clicking on the hyperlinks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to place the following code into the `Database` sheet module.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    Me.Parent.Worksheets("Foglio2").Range("A1").Value = Target.TextToDisplay
End Sub
```

Alternatively you could use:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Foglio2").Range("A1").Value = Target.Range.Value
End Sub
```

or even:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    Evaluate(Target.SubAddress).Value = Target.TextToDisplay
End Sub
```

Comment: I mistook referring to Foglio2 instead of Database, but the latter one is the one I put the code into. Thank you so much for your help VBasic2008.

Comment: Of course you did, otherwise nothing would have happened after clicking the hyperlinks. Note the third solution: think about how you could utilize it if you would want to have different `SubAddresses` (`Foglio2!A1`). Worth memorizing.

Comment: Yes...the third solution offers many possibilities in case Subadresses are many or maybe a range of cells.. I saved each one of the 3 solutions ;-)

Comment: @Mark_ I would like to remind that we here, when somebody answer our question, tick the left code side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the suggested solution works...

Comment: I have not yet marked an accepted answer because the solution provided by VBasic2008 does not work as soon as I put any of the three codes he suggested into my original project. Those solutions worked into a small example project I created in order to explain the problem. In my original project nothing happens as soon as I run any of the three codes. Maybe because the "starting table" with hyperlinks is created through a routine? I don't know why that doesn't work